# How does a Python app using pyglet add text to a ScrollableTextLayout?

Tags: text, pyglet, scrollable

From pyglet documentation and example code I've reviewed, it is not clear to me how to add text to an existing ScrollableTextLayout that is already displaying some initial text. I want to create a log of things that occur as the game is played.

Code snippet:

```
import pyglet
# width of window
progressWidth = 500
# height of window
progressHeight = 800
# caption i.e title of the window
progressTitle = "Game Progress"
# creating a window
gameProgress = pyglet.window.Window(progressWidth, progressHeight, progressTitle)
# text
actionLog = "Welcome to ALIEN SURVIVAL" + "\n" \
# batch object
progressBatch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
# creating a formatted document
# unlike unformatted document it is formatted
progressDocument = pyglet.text.document.FormattedDocument(actionLog)
# setting style to the document
progressDocument.set_style(0, len(progressDocument.text), dict(font_name='Helvetica',     font_size=14, color=(255, 255, 255, 255)))
# creating a incremental text layout
progressLayout = pyglet.text.layout.ScrollableTextLayout(progressDocument, progressWidth,     progressHeight, multiline=True, batch=progressBatch)

# on draw event
@gameProgress.event
    def on_draw():
    # clear the window
    gameProgress.clear()
    # draw the batch
    progressBatch.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

This works fine. The code I've written for mouse and keystroke scrolling also works when the initial text loaded into actionLog exceed the vertical height of the window.

However, when I concatenate more text lines onto actionLog during the game, they don't appear.
My intuitive attempt:

```
    actionLog = actionLog + "Player moved to " + str(x) + "," + str(y) + "\n"
```

What don't I understand?

I tried to repeat the progressDocument and progressLayout statements later in the program, but that overwrites what's already in the window. After several draws, the older text "glows" having been overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You are just modifying the text string, but that won't automatically update the document. You need to pass that new string to the document.

You can update the document directly using the `text` property.

```py
actionLog = actionLog + f"Player moved to x: {x}, y: {y}\n"

progressDocument.text = actionLog
```